# how to select and change custom keyboard from "AppleKeyboards"

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

i already got list of installed custom keyboard using under code but how can i select specific custom keyboard.

```
{
    ...
    AppleKeyboards =     (
        "en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY",
        "es_ES@hw=Spanish - ISO;sw=QWERTY-Spanish",
        "emoji@sw=Emoji",
        "com.swiftkey.SwiftKeyApp.Keyboard"
    );
    AppleKeyboardsExpanded = 1;
    ...
}


let bundleID = "com.companyname.appname.FontKeyboard"
            let keyboards = UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()["AppleKeyboards"] as? [Any]
            print(keyboards!)
            for keyboard: String? in keyboards as? [String?] ?? [] {
                print(keyboard!)
                if (keyboard! == bundleID) {


                }else {


                }
```

How to select or change from list of custom keyboard. i already got list of custom keyboard. but it not change or select theme daynamically, then how can i change keyoboard theme

Comment: you need to add a little more detail to your question to get a useful answer:  do you want to change the keyboard for ***only*** your app or for ***all apps*** in iOS?

Comment: i want change keyboard in app apps.

Comment: like apple system keyboard provide globe button to change keyboard, i want same .i already got all installed custom keyboard list. but how to select and change keyboard.